# WPF Style DataGridHyperlinkColumn

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I created a style for a hyperlink control:

```
<Style x:Key="MyHyperlink" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkMouseOverBrush}"  />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How can I use this style in a DataGridHyperlinkColumn?

The ElementStyle of this kind of column asks for a TextBlock style instead of an Hyperlink one...

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridTextColumn}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridHyperlinkColumn}"
                            Header="WebSite" Binding="{Binding Site, NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `x:Key` from your style and put it in `DataGrid.Resources` then it targets all `Hyperlink` controls within this `DataGrid`.

Comment: What about if I need to use this style across multiple projects?

Comment: Then put the style in a ResourceDictionary as you would do for any other style you want to reuse.

Comment: Then it applies to all Hyperlinks. 
It is annoying you cant set the style directly on the DataGridHyperLinkColumn.