# WPF - style hyperlinks in DataGrids

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I need to style hyperlinks in WPF4 DataGrid control (they appear in columns of type DataGridHyperlinkColumn). I have many DataGrids in the project and would like to apply the hyperlink style to all of them.

I found this Q&A: [WPF Style DataGridHyperlinkColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739766/wpf-style-datagridhyperlinkcolumn) and created the style for HyperLink control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="" />
</Style>
```

It works fine, but obviously it also affects all other hyperlinks, eg. in

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.co.in">Click here</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

How can I target only hyperlinks in DataGrids? In CSS syntax it would be something like

```
DataGrid Hyperlink {TextDecorations: ""; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to property value inheritance all instances of links inherits the style that you have created because you did not use **x:key** attribute.

You can add [x:Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804.aspx) attribute:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}" x:Key="HyperlinkStyle1">
    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="" />
</Style>
```

by using this you can reference this from your controls like below:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.co.in" Style={StaticResource HyperlinkStyle1}>Click here</Hyperlink>
```

Comment: I assume then that applying a custom style **only** for instances of links that has **DataGrid among it's ancestors** is not possible. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @buli - You can put a keyless style in the resources of the data grid and then only the links in the data grid will get the style, other links will have default style.

Comment: @XAMeLi - but can I apply the style do DataGrid **in general** (eg. when I create them dynamically), or just to the instance (in its resources)?

Comment: Although it's not recommended practice, you can try to create a style for the `DataGrid` and add `Style.Resources` tag where you define the style for the hyperlink. If this doesn't work, try to do it on the ControlTemplate level, i.e. `ControlTemplate.Resources`.